# Seeking Practical Examples or Guidance on Navigation in Kotlin Multiplatform with Jetpack Compose Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I am currently exploring Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMP) development and am specifically delving into navigation using Jetpack Compose Multiplatform. While I comprehend the theoretical aspects of this approach, I am struggling to find practical, implementable examples or resources online.

To implement seamless navigation between screens (composables) in a multiplatform project utilizing Jetpack Compose Multiplatform, and to understand the best practices associated with such navigation in a KMM project.

What I Tried:
I have perused the official documentation and other online resources but have mainly encountered theoretical explanations, without concrete examples or demonstrations illustrating the implementation of navigation in a real-world scenario.

Specific Queries:
Are there any recommended approaches or best practices for implementing navigation in KMM with Jetpack Compose Multiplatform?
Could anyone share practical examples or direct me to resources where I could find implementable examples or tutorials demonstrating navigation in such a context?
Are there any known limitations or caveats that I should be aware of when implementing navigation in a multiplatform project with Jetpack Compose?
I sincerely appreciate any insights, recommendations, or references that could aid me in understanding and implementing navigation in Kotlin Multiplatform with Jetpack Compose Multiplatform.

Comment: I would say best practices might be tough to come by for multiplatform specifically. You'd probably want to just go by what is recommended for Compose UI for Android. KMP Compose is rather new, and the debate is ongoing. I'm also trying to see where people think this is going. You can check out https://github.com/chrisbanes/tivi. It's a relatively complex Compose app in multiplatform. I haven't had time to dive in yet, but it's on the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can check these libraries: https://github.com/terrakok/kmp-awesome#-architecture.
I recommend you Decompose.